# CNTK Providing final LSTM state as input to another LSTM

Tags: deep-learning, cntk

I'm trying to build the following architecture:
Embeddings -> Forward LSTM -> Backward LSTM -> Concat Final States -> Concat external embedding -> LSTM

My code looks like this:

```
i = Input(features)
e = Embedding(25)(i)

# Forward and backward LSTM
h_f = Recurrence(LSTM(25), go_backwards=False)(e)
h_b = Recurrence(LSTM(25), go_backwards=True)(e)

# Get the final states and splice
f = sequence.last(h_f)
b = sequence.first(h_b)
e1 = splice(f, b)

# Get the other embedding and concat
i2 = Input(100)
e2 = Embedding(100)(i2)
e2 = sequence.first(word_embedding)
e3 = splice(e1, e2)

# Input concatenated embedding to new LSTM
r = Recurrence(LSTM(50))(e3)
```

When I do this I get the following error: 
    Input operand 'Output('Block1994_Output_0', [#], [50])' with #dynamic axes != 2 (1 sequence axis and 1 batch axis) is not supported.

If I do not get the final state of my first bidirectional LSTM then it works fine, but that's not what I want.

I can also reproduce the error with this simple example:

```
i = Input(features)
e = Embedding(25)(i)
h_f = Fold(LSTM(25), go_backwards=False)(e)
s = Recurrence(LSTM(25))(h_f)
```

Comment: Could you confirm that your goal is to create a sequence-to-sequence model? i ask because those commonly take their own output as a delayed input. if this is what you want then please check out UnfoldFrom().

Comment: should your first e2=... be word_embedding=...?

Comment: I'm not trying to train a seq2seq model. I'm trying to learn a vector representation from characters using an LSTM. Concatenate that with pre-trained word embeddings, and then input that concatenated vector into another LSTM followed by a Dense layer. And yes, you're correct about the first e2, but that's not the cause of the problem. As you can see from my second example, what I'm trying to figure out is why I can't just have the final state of one LSTM as input to another LSTM.

Answer (score 0):

check [this link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/return-sequences-and-return-states-for-lstms-in-keras/) about returning output sequences and states of an LSTM. Then, you can bind the output to the input of another layer.